# Documents folder content - The file couldn’t be opened because there is no such file

Tags: ios, swift, nsdata

Context: Xcode 8.3.2 / Swift 3

I'm downloading a bunch of MP3s in a subfolder inside the Documents folder.
Then, I'm verifying success by:

- `try FileManager.default.contentsOfDirectory(atPath: folderPath)` 
   I can see my files listed
- using Xcode, I'm doing Window - Devices - myDevice - myApp - downloadContainer. I get a copy of the sandbox on my computer's desktop. I navigate to the relevant subfolder in the Documents folder and sure enough, my MP3s are there
- last but not least...in my mobile app, I simply select one of the downloaded MP3s and hit play. It plays.

Then, I restart the application. No saved song would play again, for the above reason: **The file "name_here" couldn’t be opened because there is no such file.**
*FileManager.default.contentsOfDirectory()* still lists them there; when I check the sandbox they're all there.

I'm out of ideas.
Ideas, anyone ?

PS: the error happens when I

```
try Data.init(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: file_path_here))
```

Normally I wouldn't really need to load the stuff in memory; AVPlayer plays them just fine from disk; however, I must decrypt them first, that's why I'm populating a "NSData" with the content of whatever file. Useless to say, nothing reaches my decryptor because...**The file couldn’t be opened because there is no such file**

Why would the same code work the first time (when I download them) but fail in a later session ???

Comment: How do you calculate `file_path_here` after the app is restarted? Update your question with those details.

Comment: Look at the constructed URL for good and bad cases to see what the difference might be.

Answer (score -1):

Thanks for the hint, rmaddy.

I guess it's Friday evening, I'm tired and I should go home.

The stupidity:
At save time, the path of some file looked like

```
"/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/961ED728-311E-4BDF-A599-F79CBE59A174/Documents/NameOfMyApp/some.mp3"
```

That's what I persisted in CoreData as well, the full absolute path.

When the app restarted, I was looking for the file at that exact path. However, the application identifier changed, and my Documents folder now looked like

```
"/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/D07BF1A5-8865-4920-B96E-541D4251B553/Documents"
```

That "relativeTo" parameter in the constructor of URL() is there for a reason, I guess :-)